# HR not centering in footer

Tags: html, css

For some reason my `hr` tag is going vertically beside the footer instead of going horizontally underneath the list of links, I'm not entirely sure why it's doing this, any suggestions on how I can fix?

[image: Example]

CSS:

```
footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  }

footer div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  }

footer {
  margin-left: 25%;
  display: flex;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<footer>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Vine</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">YouTube</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Twitch</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Mobcrush</a>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">SoundCloud</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">GitHub</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Pastebin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Curse</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Minecraft Forum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Pocketmine</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">JSFiddle</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Reddit</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <hr>
</footer>
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks,

—ItzJavaCraft

Comment: I posted an answer for you, though will you have more elements below the `hr`?

Comment: @LGSon Yes,  hopefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It became a flex item. Wrap your div's and adjust the CSS accordingly and it will work.

```css
footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  }

footer div div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  }

footer > div {
  margin-left: 25%;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Vine</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul> 
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">YouTube</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Twitch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Mobcrush</a>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">SoundCloud</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">GitHub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Pastebin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Curse</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Minecraft Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Pocketmine</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">JSFiddle</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Reddit</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</footer>
```

Comment: This worked in the snippet but for some reason not on the site, the same problem occurred.

Comment: @ItzJavaCraft The snippet shows how to solve it, and if it still doesn't work on your site, you have markup/CSS rules interfere with what I used, and I can't help with that since I don't know that code.

Comment: Can I send you a link to the file? Like, JSFiddle, or Dropbox?

Comment: @ItzJavaCraft fiddle will be ok

Comment: @ItzJavaCraft Just before the line `/* SIDE NAVIGATION BAR */` in your CSS you have a second `footer` rule which you need to remove